# Tool Tip from dynamically generated text

Tags: javascript, css

I need a pointer on how to implement a tooltip from recordset values in php generated table.

Now i have a table that looks so

```
echo '<table>';

do { echo'
  <tr>
     <td class='purpose'>'.$row_recordset['Purpose'].'</td>
  </tr>';
}
while($row_recordset= mysql_fetch_array($recordset));

echo '</table>';
```

Now in css i am abbreviating the text, since this can very well be a lengthy text

```
.purpose{
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 25em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
}
```

All these work fine, But i want the full text to be displayed in a tooltip when i hover the purpose row. I cant figure out how to call each row and the content text and display in tooltip.

Help please.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: put `$row_recordset['Purpose']` in a `title` attribute of `<td class='purpose'>`

Comment: @MichaelCoker your suggestion works like magic, i didnt even realize the use of html table row title until now. Thanks.

Comment: @Ken sweet! no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
<tr>
 <td class='purpose'>'.$row_recordset['Purpose'].'</td>
</tr>';
```

to this:

```
<tr>
 <td class='purpose' title=.$row_recordset['Purpose'].'>'.$row_recordset['Purpose'].'</td>
</tr>';
```

Or if that does not work add this jquery after table

```
$('td').each(function(){
$(this).attr('title', $(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Using the html title attribute did it for me. Thanks.

Comment: You welcome. But if your data (in tds) are heavy it is better to using the second way to avoid over load.

Answer (score 0):

Something I found interesting in JQuery-UI lately is that it needs the title attribute, it does not handle undefined values so add the title attr to the  element like so:

```
echo '<table>';

do { echo'
  <tr>
     <td class='purpose' title=''>'.$row_recordset['Purpose'].'</td>
  </tr>';
}
while($row_recordset= mysql_fetch_array($recordset));

echo '</table>';
```

You can add it with the html attr title like Farzin suggested or you can add it dynamically with:

```
$(".purpose").tooltip({ content: '.$row_recordset['Purpose']' });
```

Just use a selector that fits your needs.